# Error 404 not found error

Tags: node.js, express

In my index.ejs, there is a link which links to /signup:

```
<a href="/signup"> Sign Up Here </a>
```

This is my app.js:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
//connect to mysql
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host:'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'test'
});

connection.connect();
global.db = connection;

// all environments
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

app.get('/',indexRouter); //call to index site
app.get('/login', indexRouter); // call to login site
app.get('/signup', usersRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

this is my users.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
  message = '';
   if(req.method == "POST"){
      //post data

   } else {
      res.render('signup.ejs');
   }
}); 

module.exports = router;
```

In my index page there is a link which link which directs user to a signup page. When I click on the link which is supposed to direct me to "http://localhost:3000/signup", it shows Error 404 Not found error. I am new to NodeJs. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You don't have any handler for `/signup`, so what are you expecting? A 404 is the correct response right now.

Comment: where should I handle /signup ? Do you mind to provide some guidance ?@NeilLunn

Comment: See how there is a `router.get('/'` then you need similar for `/signup`. But don't expect a tutorial from here. If you are looking for that then ask elsewhere. This site is for a solid question with a definitive answer, and not a general tutorial

Comment: @NeilLunn got it working! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Changed the link in index.ejs to

```
<a href="/users/signup"> Sign Up Here </a>
```

Added this handler to users.js

```
router.get('/signup',function(req,res,next){
  message = '';
  if(req.method == "POST"){
     //post data

  } else {
     res.render('signup');
  }
});
```